# Html border floats center postion fix

Tags: html, css

So these are my code which is CSS and then followed by html code.
What I am trying to do is center the borders inside a border and prevent them from being pushed by other borders while I shrink the window's size.
Which is make their position fixed and stay on their position in any window sizes.
I have tried everything I know to center the borders and the margin will work but the margin thing needs to depend on the computer screen size which means that if I open my website in a smaller screen of computer it will not be centered.
So I want my image stay on the center and auto fit in any sizes of screen and windows.

Which is look like this and will stay the same even if I shrink the size of the window and any other smaller or bigger size of computer screen

[image: border]

Thank you!!

```
#bodybox2{
          border-top:1px solid black;
          width:90%;
          margin-top:5%;
          padding:5%;
          background-color:grey;              
          overflow:hidden;            
         }

.imagebox{
          border:10px solid black;
          text-align:center;
          width:100%;         
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          overflow:hidden;                       
          } 

.image{
       float:left;        
       text-align:center;
       font-size:2em;
       border:1px solid black;
      }

.imageclear{
           clear:left;
           float:left;              
           text-align:center;
           font-size:2em;
           border:1px solid black;              
         }     





 <div id='bodybox2'>

   <div class="imagebox">

   <span class="image"><img src="women.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br<br>Pretty Girl</span>
   <span class="image"><img src="womenwithumbrella.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span> 
   <span class="image"><img src="women1.png"  width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>

   </div>

    <div class="imagebox">

  <span class="imageclear"><img src="shoe.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
  <span class="image"><img src="women2.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
  <span class="image"><img src="menshirt.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>

    </div>

   <div class="imagebox">

  <span class="imageclear"><img src="shoe.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
  <span class="image"><img src="women2.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
  <span class="image"><img src="menshirt.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>

    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: The first rule of centering is **don't use `float`**. Start by removing that.

Comment: They won't stick together in a line to show a row after I remove the floats..

Comment: I said... *start*! there are many, many questions about centering here on SO. I suggest you do some additional research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Paulie_D doesn't know how to click a link.
So here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
            <style>
            #bodybox2{
                      border-top:1px solid black;
                      width:90%;
                      margin-top:5%;
                      padding:5%;
                      background-color:grey;              
                      overflow:hidden;            
                     }

            .imagebox{
                      border:10px solid black;
                      text-align:center;
                      width:100%;         
                      margin-left:auto;
                      margin-right:auto;
                      overflow:hidden;  
                      display: flex;
                      justify-content: center;
                      } 

            .image{
                   float:left;        
                   text-align:center;
                   font-size:2em;
                   border:1px solid black;
                  }

            .imageclear{
                       clear:left;
                       float:left;              
                       text-align:center;
                       font-size:2em;
                       border:1px solid black;              
                     }  
            </style>
        </head>
    <body>

     <div id='bodybox2'>

       <div class="imagebox">

       <span class="image"><img src="women.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br<br>Pretty Girl</span>
       <span class="image"><img src="womenwithumbrella.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span> 
       <span class="image"><img src="women1.png"  width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>

       </div>

        <div class="imagebox">

      <span class="imageclear"><img src="shoe.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
      <span class="image"><img src="women2.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
      <span class="image"><img src="menshirt.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>

        </div>

       <div class="imagebox">

      <span class="imageclear"><img src="shoe.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
      <span class="image"><img src="women2.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>
      <span class="image"><img src="menshirt.jpg" width="300" height="400"><br><br>Pretty Girl</span>

        </div>

     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And if you want them centered, check out the `justify-center: space-between`.

Comment: It's kinda working. What I mean is it works in Chrome but not in the preview webpage on pspad which is IE :( But still a great thanks anyway!!

Comment: justify is not working in the preview webpage on pspad

Comment: For the IE you need to specify that you use the IE, here is a guide: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/